# Unity - How to change editor play/stop button positions for dual monitor layout

Tags: unity

Is it possible to change the play/stop buttons positions in editor? I am trying to make a layout for Dual-Screen, however the buttons are right in the middle of the two screen. So, it makes it hard to click the buttons.

[image]

Comment: Why not just move some individual windows to the second monitor instead of dragging the main window out?

Comment: That's how I was using it until now, but it's not as useful as docking it to editor.

Comment: Not sure if you can move the positions, but you could create some custom **EditorWindow** and use _EditorApplication.isPlaying_ to start and stop the game.